# After a reboot, BIND is unable to resolve any .org or .info domain name

Tags: linux, domain-name-system

Attempting to resolve on the BIND server itself (a CentOS 6.2 server), dig returns an empty "A" record for any domain in the .org or .info tld. 
    # dig @localhost text-lb.eqiad.wikimedia.org

```
; <<>> DiG 9.8.2rc1-RedHat-9.8.2-0.10.rc1.el6_3.2 <<>> @localhost text-lb.eqiad.wikimedia.org
; (2 servers found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: SERVFAIL, id: 58440
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;text-lb.eqiad.wikimedia.org.   IN      A

;; Query time: 156 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.1#53(127.0.0.1)
;; WHEN: Tue Jan  7 06:26:24 2014
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 45
```

However, when I tcpdump the port, this is what I see in the dump (I actually had to wade through all the CNAME stuff first, I didn't include that):

```
06:24:20.772293 IP services1i.box11.org.46014 > ns1.wikimedia.org.domain: 65338% [1au] A? text-lb.eqiad.wikimedia.org. (56)
06:24:20.864571 IP ns1.wikimedia.org.domain > services1i.box11.org.46014: 65338*- 1/3/5 A 208.80.154.224 (202)
```

It is clearly returning an A record for the domain, but the output doesn't include that A record. When I query against the google dns it all works (of course):

```
# dig @8.8.8.8 text-lb.eqiad.wikimedia.org

; <<>> DiG 9.8.2rc1-RedHat-9.8.2-0.10.rc1.el6_3.2 <<>> @8.8.8.8 text-lb.eqiad.wikimedia.org
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 17362
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;text-lb.eqiad.wikimedia.org.   IN      A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
text-lb.eqiad.wikimedia.org. 3489 IN    A       208.80.154.224

;; Query time: 61 msec
;; SERVER: 8.8.8.8#53(8.8.8.8)
;; WHEN: Tue Jan  7 06:26:16 2014
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 61
```

I don't believe I changed any configuration, but this did start happening after a reboot, so it's possible there was some odd config change lurking around (I have restarted named several times without any issue, and I'm pretty sure I haven't changed any configs since restarting named).

What I'm not getting here is why the server appears to be making the request for the A record, and it appears to be getting an answer but not returning that answer to the client. Query Logs show this one lonely entry:

```
07-Jan-2014 06:30:59.766 client 127.0.0.1#60966: view internal: query: text-lb.eqiad.wikimedia.org IN A + (127.0.0.1)
```

This was an example domain, same problem occurs with any .org or .info. Strangely, .com seems to work just fine.

Comment: Who do you do recursive lookups for?

Comment: I host my own DNS service for several low-key domains that I own. Not sure if that answers your question, though? The service is the primary DNS for all the clients on my home network, so those clients are making requests to that DNS server.

Comment: Recursive DNS means you answer DNS requests for domains that you don't host (your ISPs DNS server and 4.4.4.4/8.8.8.8 are good examples of recursive DNS servers). Do you limit who you send recursive replies to?

Comment: Nope, I do not limit who I send recursive replies to. This was a functional server, only in the last few days has it suddenly stopped resolving .org and .info domains. The test request I am making from the server itself, so I would expect it to be able to return that request unrestricted.

Comment: Yeah, that is odd, I was just wondering if you had a version of bind older or newer than 9.4.1, though even that should reply to a localhost recursion request.. this isn't great though " ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: SERVFAIL, id: 58440" SERVFAIL means something is going wrong, if there is an error you should see something in bind's logs.

Comment: Thanks to Nick for the orientation. There were no log entries that helped, but after snooping around the server, I discovered disabling dnssec explicitly caused the service to work. I then looked at the time/date on the system and found it to be almost an hour off track.. ntpd had failed to start and the clock skewed somehow. 
Syncing the clock to the correct time allowed BIND to return A records correctly. I restored the dnssec settings to the way they were (accept the default) and the system continued to work. 

SOo... the resolution was to sync the clock so it was near accurate time.

Comment: It's funny how many services want time to be accurate, but don't mention it in the error messages :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Nick for the orientation. There were no log entries that helped, but after snooping around the server, I discovered disabling dnssec explicitly caused the service to work. I then looked at the time/date on the system and found it to be almost an hour off track.. ntpd had failed to start and the clock skewed somehow. 
Syncing the clock to the correct time allowed BIND to return A records correctly. I restored the dnssec settings to the way they were (accept the default) and the system continued to work.

SOo... the resolution was to sync the clock so it was near accurate time.